# New error? No first element being used when condition has length > 1?

Tags: r

**Problem**

Notice that when I run the code on Computer 2 (R version 4.2.0)

```
if(c(1,2,3,4) == 1){ print("Hi") }
```

it is going straight to error. Is there any way to make it automatically use the first element like in Computer 1 (R version 4.1.2)?

**On Computer 1 with R version 4.1.2**
[image]

**On Computer 2 with R version 4.2.0**
[image]

Comment: But what if I want it to only consider the first element in a vector like it previously did? I recognize I could just do c(1,2,3,4)[1], but I have previous code already written out and don't want to make this change for everything.

Comment: From R 4.2.0 release news: *"Calling if() or while() with a condition of length greater than one gives an error rather than a warning."* So you need to either change the code as akrun suggests (to only check the first value use `if(c(1, 2, 3, 4)[1] == 1)`) or install an older version of R or Computer 2.

Comment: Bummer. Ok thank you for clearing that up!

Comment: I anticipate more questions like this as R-4.2 becomes more used. I agree with its change in logic from a warning to an error, but not everybody follows the "NEWS" as closely nor understands the concerns with its behavior pre-4.2.0. The dupe links provided point to potential ways around the problem (of length > 1 in an `if` conditional), so ignore their mention of "warning" and skip right to the remediation suggestions, including `ifelse` or `isTRUE` or `[1]`.